# How can I rotate this rectangle 90 degrees?

Tags: graphs

How are members of the page. I'm trying to make this homotopy diagram. I'm trying to rotate the rectangle that appears in the image 90 degrees. How could I do this in the code. Thank you. This is the code I have:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$H: I \times I \rightarrow G$};
\node[label=below:$z_1$]  (x1) at (6,0)  {$\bullet$};
\node[label=above:$z_0$]  (x0) at (9,4)  {$\bullet$};  
\node  at (9.5,2)  {$\subset G$}; 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=5,in=-90]++(2.8,1.8) to[out=90,in=-95](x0.center);
\draw (x1.center) to [out=10,in=-110]++(2.6,2) to[out=70,in=-103] 
(x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=15,in=-105](x0.center);
\draw (x1.center) to [out=30,in=-150](x0.center);
\draw (x1.center) to [out=45,in=-170](x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=50,in=-105]++(1.2,3)to [out=75,in=-172] 
(x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=55,in=-100]++(1.0,3) to[out=80,in=-175] 
(x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=60,in=-90]++(0.8,3) to[out=90,in=-180] 
(x0.center);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw, anchor=text, rectangle split,
rectangle split parts=7,minimum width=2cm}]
\node (R) at (2,4){ \nodepart{two} \nodepart{three}
\nodepart{four}$I\times I$\nodepart{five}\nodepart{six}\nodepart{seven}};
\end{scope}
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=6pt,amplitude=10pt}, thick]
(R.north west)--(R.south west) ;
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=6pt,amplitude=10pt}, thick]
(R.north east)--(R.south east); 
\draw[->] ($(R.west)+(-20pt,0)$) to[out=-180,in=240] ++(0,2)
to [out=60,in=120]node[above,midway]{$H(0,t)$}(x0) ; 
\draw[->] ($(R.north)+(0,10pt)$) to [out=60,in=120]
node[above,midway]{$\gamma_0 \simeq \gamma_1$} ++(4.5,-1) ; 
\draw[->] ($(R.east)+(20pt,0)$)  to [out=0,in=140]
node[right,midway]{$H(1,t)$}(x1) ; 
\draw[->] ($(R.south)+(0,-20pt)$)  to [out=-85,in=-30]
node[below,midway]{$\alpha$}++(7,0) ;    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)? In the previous version of your code several tikz libraries  were missing  and now we have to guess even more.

Comment: Apologies. I copied and pasted a different code. The one that appears now in the publication is the correct one.

Comment: OK, then please add the necessary parts to make your new code into a compilable document.

Comment: Now is already ok!

Comment: A minimal working example needs to include `\documentclass`, the preamble (with `\usepackage` and `tikzlibrary`, etc) as well as `\begin{document}` and `\end{document}`. This makes it so that it can be compiled, and makes it more convenient for others to help you.

Comment: Now is already ok! user496634!

Comment: You can rotate the rectangle by adding `,rotate=-90,transform shape` to the options scope in which you draw it. Or do `,rotate around={-90:(2,2)},transform shape` if you want to rotate it about the point at `(2,2)`.

Comment: Hello marmot. I did that and it worked but now my graph is overlapping and the arrows do not match.

Comment: Yes, the issue with the coordinates happens because some coordinates are essentially hardcoded. The overlap can be avoided by rotating about some appropriate point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The splitted rectangle shape has a switch to make it horizontal: `rectangle split horizontal=true`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw, anchor=text, rectangle split,
rectangle split parts=7,minimum height=2cm,rectangle split horizontal}]
\node (R) at (2,4){};
\end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

---

Full MWE (some of the hard coded coordinates have to be adjusted):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,calc,shapes,decorations.pathreplacing}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {$H: I \times I \rightarrow G$};
\node[label=below:$z_1$]  (x1) at (6,0)  {$\bullet$};
\node[label=above:$z_0$]  (x0) at (9,4)  {$\bullet$};  
\node  at (9.5,2)  {$\subset G$}; 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=5,in=-90]++(2.8,1.8) to[out=90,in=-95](x0.center);
\draw (x1.center) to [out=10,in=-110]++(2.6,2) to[out=70,in=-103] 
(x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=15,in=-105](x0.center);
\draw (x1.center) to [out=30,in=-150](x0.center);
\draw (x1.center) to [out=45,in=-170](x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=50,in=-105]++(1.2,3)to [out=75,in=-172] 
(x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=55,in=-100]++(1.0,3) to[out=80,in=-175] 
(x0.center); 
\draw (x1.center) to [out=60,in=-90]++(0.8,3) to[out=90,in=-180] 
(x0.center);
\begin{scope}[every node/.style={draw, anchor=text, rectangle split,
rectangle split parts=7,minimum height=2cm,rectangle split horizontal}]
\node (R) at (0,2){ \nodepart{two} \nodepart{three}
\nodepart{four}\rotatebox{90}{$I\times I$}\nodepart{five}\nodepart{six}\nodepart{seven}};
\end{scope}
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=6pt,amplitude=10pt}, thick]
(R.north west)--(R.south west) ;
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=6pt,amplitude=10pt}, thick]
(R.north east)--(R.south east); 
\draw[->] ($(R.west)+(-20pt,0)$) to[out=-180,in=240] ++(0,2)
to [out=60,in=120]node[above,midway]{$H(0,t)$}(x0) ; 
\draw[->] ($(R.north)+(0,10pt)$) to [out=60,in=120] node[above,midway]{$\gamma_0 \simeq \gamma_1$} ++(5.4,0.4) ; 
\draw[->] ($(R.east)+(20pt,0)$)  to [out=0,in=140]
node[right,midway]{$H(1,t)$}(x1) ; 
\draw[->] ($(R.south)+(0,-20pt)$)  to [out=-85,in=-30]
node[below,midway]{$\alpha$}++(7,0) ;    
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(The idea to rotate `I \times I` is borrowed from @marmot - thanks a lot for the idea!)

Comment: thanks @samcarter and thanks and marmot four your help.

Comment: `rectangle split horizontal` is a true Boolean by default, it is useless to add `=true`

Comment: @AndréC Thanks a lot for your comment. I updated my answer.